# Upload huge data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have to upload a crores of data into mysql table. The data is in the form of .csv format. I was tried with load infile method. but, it is also taking very long time. Is there any other way to upload a data ?

Comment: @seeker There is 1 crore record per file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Load Data statement of MYSQL -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed. The file name must be given as a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

There is a MySQL utility called mysqlimport http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

I suggest to try that.

**EDIT** Actually it seems to be the same as `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Answer (score 0):

You can find some usefull tuning tips here:

- [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html)
- [Bulk Data Loading for MyISAM Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html)
- [Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

Hope this helps